# How do I pass a string from UIViewController back to a SwiftUI View (iOS)

Tags: swiftui

I need to use AVFoundation for an app I'm writing.  Basically scanning a barcode, and sending that information back to another ViewController.  This was pretty easy/straight forward with Swift and UIKit and I had this working.

Now, I launch the ViewController using a sheet (passing in the @State variable so I can dismiss the sheet later):

```
.sheet(isPresented: $isShowingCamera, content: {
    ScanItem(isPresented: self.$isShowingCamera)
})
```

ScanItem is a UIViewRepresentable
Here are the functions in ScanItem:

```
func makeCoordinator() -> ScanItem.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(self)
}

public typealias UIViewControllerType = ScanBarcodeViewController

func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ScanItem>) -> ScanBarcodeViewController {
    return ScanBarcodeViewController()
}

func updateViewController(_ uiViewController: ScanBarcodeViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ScanItem>) {
}
```

Inside I have the required methods and its displaying another UIViewController I created that uses AVFoundation to display the camera, and look for the barcode.  Where I believe I need to progress is making the Coordinator handle the AVCaptureMetaData.  I have the Coordinator like below:

```
class Coordinator: NSObject, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    let parent: ScanItem
    init(_ parent: ScanItem) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    let metaDataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
    if metaDataObj.stringValue != nil {
        self.parent.$metadata = metadataObj.stringValue
        self.parent.$isPresented = false
    }
}
```

I think I'm on the right track here.  This function gets called normally in the extension of the viewcontroller as AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate.  I think I need to set the Coordinator as the delegate, call the function, set some bindable variable  (@Bindable var metadata: String) and handle it in the SwiftUI view.

My current errors:
ScanBarcodeViewController (my viewcontoller to load the camera) cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
Which goes along with
class ScanBarcodeViewController has not initializers
self.parent.$metaData = metaDataObj.stringValue -> cannot assign value of type String to type Binding  -- fixed
self.parent.$isPresented = false -> cannot assign value of type Bool to type Binding -- fixed

Answer (score 1):

Instead of passing self in Coordinator (which is struct, so copied), ie

```
Coordinator(self)
```

use binding to your model directly, so you can modify it, ie like

```
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    return Coordinator(data: $metadata)
}
```

and in Coordinator..

```
final class Coordinator: NSObject, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var data: Binding<String>
```

...

```
func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    let metaDataObj = metadataObjects[0] as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject
    if metaDataObj.stringValue != nil {
        ...
        data.wrappedValue = metadataObj.stringValue
        ...
    }
}
```